# Cборка проекта pyinstaller. Ошибка ImportError: cannot import name 'opengl_arrays_modules'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

Написал небольшой проект на python3. Из сторонних библиотек использую только pygame. Но при сборке приложения происходит ошибка:

```
 in <module>
    from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import opengl_arrays_modules
ImportError: cannot import name 'opengl_arrays_modules'
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Если надо, то вот весть вывод pyinstaller:

```
C:\Users\vmn3w\Desktop\freel>pyinstaller main.py
286 INFO: PyInstaller: 4.0
286 INFO: Python: 3.6.7
287 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.18362-SP0
302 INFO: wrote C:\Users\vmn3w\Desktop\freel\main.spec
307 INFO: UPX is not available.
315 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\Users\\vmn3w\\Desktop\\freel', 'C:\\Users\\vmn3w\\Desktop\\freel']
424 INFO: checking Analysis
425 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent
425 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
431 INFO: Caching module graph hooks...
510 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
12646 INFO: Caching module dependency graph...
12873 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
12877 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies of final executable
  required by c:\users\vmn3w\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python.exe
13136 INFO: Analyzing C:\Users\vmn3w\Desktop\freel\main.py
17086 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook distutils from 'c:\\users\\vmn3w\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python36\\lib\\site-packages\\
PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_find_module_path\\hook-distutils.py'.
17087 INFO: distutils: retargeting to non-venv dir 'c:\\users\\vmn3w\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python36\\lib'
20640 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook setuptools.extern.six.moves from 'c:\\users\\vmn3w\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python36\\
lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_safe_import_module\\hook-setuptools.extern.six.moves.py'.
22015 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook site from 'c:\\users\\vmn3w\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python36\\lib\\site-packages\\PyIns
taller\\hooks\\pre_find_module_path\\hook-site.py'.
22017 INFO: site: retargeting to fake-dir 'c:\\users\\vmn3w\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python36\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\fake-modu
les'
35987 INFO: Processing module hooks...
35987 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-OpenGL.py' from 'c:\\users\\vmn3w\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python36\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstall
er_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\vmn3w\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts\pyinstaller-script.py", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('pyinstaller==4.0', 'console_scripts', 'pyinstaller')())
  File "c:\users\vmn3w\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 114, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "c:\users\vmn3w\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 65, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\vmn3w\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 720, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
  File "c:\users\vmn3w\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 667, in build
    exec(code, spec_namespace)
  File "C:\Users\vmn3w\Desktop\freel\main.spec", line 17, in <module>
    noarchive=False)
  File "c:\users\vmn3w\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 242, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "c:\users\vmn3w\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", line 160, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "c:\users\vmn3w\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 419, in assemble
    self.graph.process_post_graph_hooks()
  File "c:\users\vmn3w\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 365, in process_post_graph_ho
oks
    module_hook.post_graph()
  File "c:\users\vmn3w\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\imphook.py", line 440, in post_graph
    self._load_hook_module()
  File "c:\users\vmn3w\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\imphook.py", line 407, in _load_hook_module
    self.hook_module_name, self.hook_filename)
  File "c:\users\vmn3w\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\compat.py", line 588, in importlib_load_source
    return mod_loader.load_module()
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 399, in _check_name_wrapper
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 823, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 682, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 265, in _load_module_shim
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 684, in _load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "c:\users\vmn3w\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\hooks\stdhooks\hook-OpenGL.py", line 24,
 in <module>
    from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import opengl_arrays_modules
ImportError: cannot import name 'opengl_arrays_modules'
```

Answer (score 0):

Разработчики `Pyinstaller` недавно внесли изменения в хуки. Мне кажется, что у вас остались старые хуки от предыдущей установки `PyInstaller`, он не будет работать, поскольку они также внесли изменения в код.
Попробуйте переустановить `PyInstaller`. Может есть метод попроще, но я покажу вам тот, что знаю сам:

Консоль виндовс:

`pip uninstall pyinstaller` (вам выведется ещё подтверждение, отправите `y`)

Затем, после удаления (которое мы как раз и провели выше), снова в консоль пишем, но уже:
`pip install pyinstaller`

(если у вас установлена так же `python2`, то используйте `pip3`, вместо `pip`)

---

Всем добра-бобра

Comment: К сожалению у меня сейчас самая последняя версия pyinstaller(

Comment: Самое интересное, что я частично решил проблему установив pyinstaller==3.6. main.exe который в папке build не запускался, но я смог запустить main.exe в папке dist.